# How can I extend the expiration time of an STS token for Aliyun roles accessed through Vault?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I can not extend the expiration time of an STS token for Aliyun roles accessed through Vault

1，I set the maximum time for the RAM role in alicloud to 2 hours.
2,On the Vault side, I executed two commands as follows:

```
vault secrets tune -default-lease-ttl=2h alicloud/
vault secrets tune -max-lease-ttl=24h alicloud/
```

The results are as follows:

```
Local   No
Seal wrap   No
Default Lease TTL   7200
Max Lease TTL   86400
```

3,The information returned by the command `vault read alicloud/creds/appname` is still 1 hour. The returned information is as follows:

```
Key                Value
---                -----
lease_id           alicloud/creds/appname/xxxxx
lease_duration     59m59s
lease_renewable    false
```

Where did I make a mistake? I can't extend this time to 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

solved ! When Vault calls the Alibaba Cloud interface, it does not pass in a TTL (Time To Live) duration, so no matter how long the set time is, the duration can only be Alibaba Cloud's default time of 1 hour.
Thank you to the expert for his answer.
link https://blog.liuliancao.com/roams/2022-12-12-vault/